# Ext JS 4: Unable to see dynamic data for comboxbox

Tags: extjs

I am trying to render editable combo inside the grid. Below is my code snippet

```
columns: [
         {
             text     : 'Account Name',
             name      : 'accountName', 
             width     : 80,    
             flex     : 4,                                      
             sortable : true,
             dataIndex: 'accountName'
          },
          {
             text     : 'Account Number',
                 name      : 'accountNumber',
             flex     : 2,                                        
             sortable : false,                               
             dataIndex: 'accountNumber',
             editor      : {'combobox',
                     typeAhead       : true,
                     selectOnTab     : true,
                     lazyRender      : true,
                     triggerAction   : 'all',
                     listClass       : 'x-combo-list-small',
                      queryMode       : 'local',
                      store           : emptyStore,

            },                                              

                    displayField    : 'acctNumber',
                    valueField      : 'acctNumber',
                    listeners: {
                            afterrender: function(comboField, eOpts)
                             {
                                // have to add two sub accounts - 1. account number of column 2.account number of column + "1" 
                               // first try with hard coded values
          var employeesStore = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({

          fields:['acctNumber'],
          data:[{acctNumber: '123456'},{acctNumber: '23456'}]
          })

         comboField.bindStore(employeesStore);
            }  
           }

         }



      },
```

But, when I run, I get the drop down with two empty lines

Can someone help me?

Thanks
Tharahan

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's doing this is because the dataIndex's on your columns do not map to any fields in the store which is bound to the grid. If you change `dataIndex: 'accountNumber'` to `dataIndex: 'acctNumber'`, you'll see the data. Also, you don't have a "accountName" field in the store which is bound to the grid, so you won't see any data for that until you add a field (and corresponding data) to your store.

Comment: Sorry for not adding the entire grid. The grid uses different store which has accountName and accountNumber. Then, for editor, I am trying bring up a drop down with two items in it. One is the account number ("123456") of the grid store. and the other with  account number added 1 at the end (123456-1).